# PostgreSQL asymmetric replication

Tags: postgresql, replication, database-replication

I've got a central database on a server and a lot of databases installed in my clients' laptops. I need to replicate the databases but I only know the IP address of the central database.

- The laptops' IP addresses change every day

Do you know a daemon that synchronizes the databases with the central database? This daemon needs to be installed on my clients' laptops, I should not install anything on the central database server.

- This is the same synchronization that Android's applications use to work in offline mode.

All the databases are Postgres. From each client laptop I need to push the new rows and pull changes from the central database.

Comment: So you want disconnected asynchronous two-way database sync. You're going to need something at the application level for this that understands the data and can resolve conflicts. Use triggers on each end to record and queue changes.